# Spring MVC with Hibernate Lists

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

So I've got some tables set up in Oracle, and using Spring MVC I'm able to get a list of all objects in each table and show them in a jsp using a spring form select.  Now I can't seem to figure out how to allow the user to select one, retain which one the user selects and then do things with the OBJECT that they select.  I was able to get the string they selected, but this doesn't help since I need the actual Object that was selected.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    GenericDAO<Material> matDAO;

    @Autowired
    GenericDAO<Structure> structDAO;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getForm(){

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("testForm");

        return model;

    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public void displayForm(Model model){
        List<Structure> structList = structDAO.retrieveAll(Structure.class);
        model.addAttribute("structure", new Structure());
        model.addAttribute("structList", structList);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/submitChoices.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getStruct(@ModelAttribute("structure") Structure struct){

        //Manipulate Structure Object Here

    } 


}
```

JSP PAGE:

```
<body>

<springform:form method="POST" action="/project/submitchoices.html">

    <springform:select>
        <springform:option value="0" label="--- Select One ---"/>
        <springform:options items="${structList}" itemValue="type" itemLabel="type"/>

    </springform:select>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</springform:form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an ID of the object for each option so that each option can be identified by Hibernate.  The ID ties you back to which object was selected.  Right now you only have structList.  Notice above there is a value="0".  In each of the actual selects that get populated, those also need values.

Comment: In my structure class, I have the fields "type" and "sID" where "sID" is the primary key.  Could I just change itemValue in the above JSP to "sID"?

Comment: I would use ${sID} in place of type; then when you get back to the controller you can use the id to retrieve and/or work with that object since you know which one it is.

Comment: That doesn't work.  I think the $ sign is only for getting something from the controller and into the .jsp using model.addattribute() from the controller.  If I change itemValue to "sID", which is a field in my "structure" table, it should pass the id of the one selected to the getStruct() method.  However, it's not working either, and it just gives me "0", meaning that I'm not actually getting an Id.

Comment: Maybe I'm not quite on the same page as you since all your code isn't here.  Check out this example.  He even has a downloadable example to play with.
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/